# easyXDM, AJAX and Enjin

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, easyxdm

This is going to be about the same issue as my previous question ([Loading a php file into cross domain page with dynamic element height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15092103/loading-a-php-file-into-cross-domain-page-with-dynamic-element-height)) but now with trying to use a new method.

I found a way to load my script into an ajax div locally but there still remains the issue of cross domain security not allowing the xmlhttprequest to call to my other server.

The issues here is still that on Site A, which is my web server that I have full access to and is hosting my scripting files, I can do whatever I want with the script and make it work. On Site B, which is the on Enjin server, I have no access to host scripts. I can place .js scripts there and run those, but I can't use php from their servers which creates my issue. To get around this right now, I am using an iframe, which is inefficient to say the least. It can't load a dynamic height from the contents being generated by the php file it is calling from Site A. I planned on fixing this with loading this into a div via AJAX but I am having a few issues with that.

My AJAX script is this:

```
<pre><code>function Ajax(){
    var xmlHttp;
        try{    
            xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest();// Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        }
        catch (e){
            try{
                xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
            }
            catch (e){
                try{
                    xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                catch (e){
                    alert("No AJAX!?");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
            document.getElementById('ReloadThis').innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
            setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET","http://sitea.com/twitch_api/stream_header.php",true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

    window.onload=function(){
        setTimeout('Ajax()',10000);
    }
</code></pre>
```

then obviously the div is following the script.

the script that this is calling is this:

http://pastebin.com/mC8kakKJ

Sorry, can't get all the code to parse correctly in the code block but i made a pastebin copy of the script

My questions here become. What does my script need to look like for use with easyXDM? I have no experience with a library like this or cors, so an example markup would be awesome.

I am also not all that versed in javascript/ajax which leads to my second question. I my ajax code listed above, how would i go about having that div populate with the desired file immediately then update every 300000ms (5 minutes).

Any help is appreciated. Have a post on the Enjin forums but not too many there have experience going to this depth.

Answer (score 0):

You could use $.getJSON(), Enjin pages use jQuery. Just make sure your server response is wrapped in a callback function so the cross site request is allowed.